# AngularJS Routing with Web.API Visual studio project

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I have a problem introducing the routing in a webapi project, created in VS2017. I use the lastest vesion of angular. This is the source:

app.angular

```
angular.module('angularapp', [
'ngRoute',
'ngCookies',
'ngAnimate',
'angular-loading-bar'
```

])

```
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/login', {
            templateUrl: 'login.aspx'
    })

        .when('/', {
            templateUrl: '/login.aspx'
        })

        .when('/404', {
            templateUrl: '/404.aspx'
        })

        .when('/home', {
            templateUrl: '/home.aspx'
        })       

        .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode({
        enabled: true,
        requireBase: false
    });
}])
```

On project launch, IIS result is 404. Obviusly, I loaded angular, then ngroute, then the controllers. There is a master page where I load globally all css and js on all the other page are aspx. Each page have a controller. I am missing something o there are some errors in the files? Need other info?
Thanks for help

**EDIT**

Code over modify.
I modify the web.confing in this way:

```
<system.webServer>
<validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
<modules></modules>
<handlers>
  <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
  <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
  <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler" />
  <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
</handlers>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="AngularJS Routes" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <clear />
    <add value="login.aspx"/>
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
```

Login now is loading, but I have a problem with injection module... I don't know where. If I login correctly, IIS reload always login.

Comment: You said you have aspx pages, but the information you're including is related to Web API routing. The first thing you show is your empty route config that looks to be for MVC, so if you are using ASP.NET MVC with aspx views, then I'm guessing your 404 is related to your MVC routing, not Web API.

Comment: I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45828004/angular-html5mode-in-visual-studio-website/45828677#45828677). In short, you need to add a rewrite rule to your web.config

Comment: @MatthewCawley great! now is working, but not as well. See Edit for detail and reviewed code. Thanks :)

Comment: @MicheleBoscagin What error are you getting?